# curl strange output

Tags: macos, curl, terminal

I am trying to download nodejs tar files from server using curl.. but its outputting strange characters to terminal and also not downloading the file. Check the screenshot

I am typing this command on terminal

```
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.8.tar.gz
```

Why showing strange characters as output. I have also tried

```
curl -0 http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.8.tar.gz
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add -O to not dump the file contents to the terminal.

curl -O http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.8.tar.gz

Note that it is the captital o and not zero.

For more, I can recommend
http://www.tuaw.com/2007/03/05/monday-man-page-curl/

Answer (score 0):

try `curl -O http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.8.tar.gz` meaning letter `O`, not zero `0`